# Style progress tag of HTML 5 in Mozilla browser

Tags: html

I'm not so familiar in styling the progress bar in HTML 5. Can someone help me in removing the border outline of the progress bar when I run it on Mozilla browser.

```css
progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  appearance: none;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #FF5800;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progress_fileUpload" value="60" max="100"></progress>
```

**The output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add
`border:none;` to your current css :)

also the code you provided is not putting out the same code as the picture is displaying i recommend using the same code to recieve better help

Comment: Did you tried it to run in a mozilla browser? because that's the time that it will look like that...it will looks fine if you are using chrome.. I already did border:none but it does not solve my problem

Comment: Thank you for the idea of "border:none"  :)  I just have to put in the style of  progress tag..

Comment: if the answer works for you then please accept it i would much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

In my css code I just add :

```
progress {
    color: #FF5800;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
    border:none;
}
```

and it works fine in Mozilla :)

```css
progress[value] {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  appearance: none;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background: #FF5800;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progress_fileUpload" value="60" max="100"></progress>
```